# All versions of Clojure jars report to be Clojure-1.7.0-RC1, regardless of actual version

Tags: java, clojure

When I download a copy of Clojure (`1.8.0` or any other version), either from Maven Central or the official website, it will claim to be version `1.7.0-RC1`.

For example:

`$ java -jar clojure-1.8.0.jar
Clojure 1.7.0-RC1
user=>`

It also seems that this is, in fact, the version that is run. Since functions that were added in 1.8.0 (specifically `string/starts-with?`) are not available in the repl (after importing).

When an identical copy of the file (verified by shasum) is downloaded on a separate laptop, the correct version runs.

I have verified this with several versions, including `1.8.0`, `1.9.0-alpha17`, and `1.5.0-RC2`. All of them report as `1.7.0-RC1`.

Additional information:

`$ java -version
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)`

Using macOS version `10.12.3`.

Comment: Can't reproduce. sha1sum(s) follow - `unzip ~/Downloads/clojure-1.8.0.zip` then `java -jar clojure-1.8.0/clojure-1.8.0.jar 
Clojure 1.8.0
user=>`

Comment: `313066c972b6b00f390674bf0e9f732c07f205a4  clojure-1.8.0/clojure-1.8.0.jar`

Comment: `93e9dd5559225d219b557b418bfcabd5c2a2ade6  ~/Downloads/clojure-1.8.0.zip`

Comment: Those match the sha1sum(s) I get as well. I also cannot reproduce this on a separate laptop.

Comment: What does `(System/getProperty "java.class.path")` return?

Comment: `"clojure-1.8.0.jar"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another (older) version of Clojure `.jar` may load and override the one specified on command line (or classpath), if you have installed the older `Clojure 1.7.0-RC1` as a ["Java Extension" on macOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/01-JavaOverview/JavaOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001883-205668-TPXREF112). In practise, your reported behaviour results from placing the 1.7.0 `.jar` in `/Library/Java/Extensions/` or `~/Library/Java/Extensions/` (under your home directory).

A simple solution is to remove the `jar` file from the Extensions folder.

The [Java Development Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/01-JavaOverview/JavaOverview.html) actually warns about the perils of using the Extensions directory, as it can lead to such problems:

> Try to include all of your dependent libraries in your application rather than relying on the Java Extensions directory, because its contents are unversioned and cannot accommodate for multiple versions of the same library.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. I thought I was going crazy for a while there.